# Storing JSON data from Bloomberg API and storing it in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, flask, bloomberg

So i'm succesfully pulling requests from Bloomberg's OpenAPI, and the data comes out in JSON format. I want to store this data in a MongoDB document that will act as the database from which the data will be queried. Any help with this? thanks!

Some other info: I'm trying to set a flask document that uses PyMongo in order to populate the database.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse I am not entirely sure on the details of the data, but this is the general flow of interacting with MongoDB using `pymongo`.

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Create a connection to the mongodb instance. Passing no parameters will connect to default host (localhost) and port (27017)
connection = MongoClient()

# Store the database reference in a variable
db = connection.bloomberg

# Get the collection
collection = db.<whatever-you-want-the-collection-name-to-be>

# Assuming the response of the API is a json string in a variable line
collection.insert(json.loads(line))
```

This is how you store a JSON document in a MongoDB collection. Getting the data out of a MongoDB collection is straight-forward and I am sure the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one) talks about it.